# How can i know if a session is still active or not?

Tags: php, session

I'm storing the sessions ids in a database table. I
  want to run a script that reads from the table every
  session id and check if this session is active or not.

I know that session information is stored in a
  directory (`/tmp` by default) and removed from there
  when the session is closed. But if the user close his
  browser without disconnecting from the session the
  session file is still in the `/tmp` directory.

How can I know if a session is still active or not?

I have searched the session functions and didn't find
  anything that could help.

Comment: I don't think that you can, but I hope I'm wrong

Answer (score 6):

Generally speaking, the only way is to have a "last used" datetime/timestamp which you update every time the session is referenced, and discard/deactivate sessions after they haven't been used for a certain amount of time.

It's not possible to tell if a session will be referenced further as they're not kept open between requests, simply referenced when needed ... and need is dictated by the ever fickle client.

If your sessions are file based, as it sounds, you can use the [last accessed date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fileatime.php) of the individual files, possibly save yourself a bit of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

If you are keeping sessions in the database. Add a last accessed or modified timestamp to the database table.  I've put code in my procedures that retrieve or store session information that DELETE FROM sessions WHERE modified is more than an hour ago.  However long you want your session to be. At every call you can update that timestamp.  It seems that would cause a performance hit, but I've used that pattern/process quite a bit. I almost always use the database to store session information.  You should research [session_set_save_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).  I can try to gather some of my own code from previous project where I utilized this, but I'm sure that reading the manual on this and googling implementations will help you quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you care about this already outdated sessions? They will be cleared from temporary folder in some random time anyway.

You should check last access time in your database and if it's more then some predefined timeout - mark it as dead.

But think about your performance too. It's a way better approach to store your session data in **memcache** or something similar to it - just store it in memory, not in DB. Read more about it here: http://memcached.org/

It's really easy to store your session data in memcached: http://www.dotdeb.org/2008/08/25/storing-your-php-sessions-using-memcached/

Comment: I disagree, You have a slight performance hit, database calls especially if they are on the same server which a lot of LAMP installs are set up that way, are negligible.  By moving that type of functionality to the database makes the application more scale-able, allowing easier transition to failovers and load balancing when you need it.

Comment: @stephenbayer, now think about 500 concurrent users accessing your site and several search bots from Google, Yahoo, etc. accessing other pages. Your database will soon be overwhelmed with queries to sessions table. Talking about load-balancing - every in-memory store engine like memcached can be easily scaled with unlimited server instances. Moreover, PHP API for memcached make everything for you, programmer will not even think about what server is actually used from memcached cluster when calling Mcached API.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a function. 
PHP itself use somewhat an hack to determine when a session is expired, there are several
options into the php.ini configuration file.

In short, every time a session started there is a [gc_probability](http://it.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability)/[gc_divisor](http://it.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor) chanche that php will start a
garbage collection of pending data. 
The session accessed before [gc_maxlifetime](http://it.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) seconds are considered expired and PHP deletes them.

You can relay on this behaviour tuning the envolved options or mimic this behaviour with a
similar approach.

For reference:

- http://it.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime
- http://it.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability
- http://it.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor